# Null check using Optional for By/BySelector

Tags: java, android-uiautomator

I want to re-write my null checking code, and use Optional instead.

```
public BySelector select(BySelector bySelector, Boolean value) {
  return (bySelector == null) ? By.checkable(value) : bySelector.checkable(value);
}
```

The above is my original code. I have no idea how to replace to Optional. I've tried the following but it is not working. Please advise. Thank you.

```
public BySelector select(BySelector bySelector, Boolean value) {
  return Optional.ofNullable(bySelector.checkable(value).orElse(By.checkable(value);
}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What are you expecting? What results do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use Optional in your case as it is less clear than your simple null check, but this is how I would do :

```java
Optional.ofNullable(bySelector)
        .map(x -> By.checkable(value))
        .orElse(BySelector.checkable(value));
```

Maybe you want your method to return an optional, which makes more sense.

Comment: The authors of `Optional` have stated that, "Optional is intended to provide a **limited** mechanism for library method **return types** where there is a clear need to represent 'no result' and where using null for that is **overwhelmingly likely to cause errors.**" (Emphasis in original) Not a single one of those conditions is met in this case.

Comment: @Tkim Thanks for your help. It works after I swap line 2 and 3 from you code.